# Windows 10.0.19043.1320 Pro (21H1) and NFS Share: MOUNT.EXE missing

Tags: linux, windows-10, nas, samba, nfs

I have a [Terra Master F5-221 NAS](https://www.terra-master.com/us/f5-221.html) with SAMBA/CIFS and NFS shares. The SAMBA shares can be accessed no problem; just open Windows Explorer and put `\\NASIPADDRESS\sharename` as the address. But that is VERY slow, like *kilobytes-per-second-slow* for lots of small files. So I want to try NFS.

Researching, Win10 Pro does not come with NFS services enabled by default, which is explained in [this somewhat dated article by Tony Mackay](https://graspingtech.com/mount-nfs-share-windows-10/). Ok, so get NFS services enabled, but then when `mount -o anon \NASIPADDRESS\mnt\md0\sharename` is tried, I'm greeted with the lovely `'mount' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Researching further, the only `mount.exe` and `umount.exe` is in a buried folder inside WinSxS. Trying those, they complain they are 16-bit only.

**On this more-modern version of Windows 10, how do I get the `mount` command?** Or is there another way to connect to a (Linux) NFS share from Win10.0.19043.1320?

*Edit: Windows Powershell does have a 'mount' command, but this appears to be for 'NDR' or 'New-PSDrive'; nothing to do with NFS.*  [MS Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nfs/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) does list some NFS tools for Win10 PS, but none of these are for *mounting* a share in Windows.

*Edit 2: Tried this at work (Win10.19042.1320 Pro) and I get a mount command here. Will re-check home system but think I've found the problem.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary from the article
[How to Mount an NFS Share Using a Windows 10 Machine](https://graspingtech.com/mount-nfs-share-windows-10/).
This requires at least the Windows Pro version 10.0.14393 and above.

**Install the NFS Client (Services for NFS)**

1. Open Programs and Features, or search for "Windows Features."
2. Click "Turn Windows Features On or Off."
3. Check "Services for NFS" and expand it. Ensure all items are checked.
   [image: Windows 10 add Services for NFS]
4. Click OK, Close, and exit back to the desktop.

**Enable Write Permissions for the Anonymous User**

Without this step, the NFS mount is done in read-only mode.

- Run `regedit` and navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default`
- Create two new "DWORD (32-bit)" values inside the "Default" folder:

  - `AnonymousUid` with the UID found on the UNIX directory
    as shared by the NFS system
  - `AnonymousGid` with the GID of the above
- Restart the NFS client or reboot the computer to apply the changes.

**Mount the NFS Share**

The NAS device must be on the same network as the Windows machine.
If for example its IP address is `10.1.1.211`, use the following command
to mount the share on the NFS system at `/mnt/vms`:

```
mount -o anon \\10.1.1.211\mnt\vms Z:
```

You may now navigate to the `Z:` drive.

Comment: Harry, the issue is that in this particular build of Win10, just checking "Services for NFS" does *not* automatically check "Administrative Tools" and "Client for NFS."  It must be explicitly opened and checked.

Comment: Please note, when opening Command Prompt to mount the NFS drive, don't use "Run as Administrator". It will mount and you can navigate to the drive in command prompt, but the drive won't appear in Windows Explorer (aka My Computer/This PC).